# Kernel panic after LVM group rename

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS 6.3 VM running and I got the error message below after I did [`lvm group rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgrename) and rebooted (SELinux running).

```
vgrename vg_name1 vg_name2
reboot
```

The error message is:

> Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Screenshot

[image: kernel panic]

How to solve this boot problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem.  In my case the issue was that I had renamed the devices, but not told my bootloader about it.

I booted using a live CD/DVD, found and mounted my boot filesystem, then edited the bootloader configuration (i.e. /grub/grub.conf).  I corrected the names of the LVM disks in that file to their new versions, then rebooted and all was fine.

Comment: Yep, i deleted a secondary swap file from LVM but forgot to remove it from grub command line.  Did not use a LiveCD but edited grub command line at initial bootup.  Then once i was booted up, edited /etc/grub..conf.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling its SELinux causing the problem. Try the following

Reboot the machine. When the Grub menu shows up, hit the up/down key. Then hit the 'A' key. You will enter a minimal shell for Grub. Add the following after whatever is on the screen

selinux=0 enforcing=0

And then hit enter. Let us know what happens. Ideally you should be taken to the login prompt. You then need to figure out why SELinux is causing trouble. You might want to start with the messages log. You could technically disable SELinux and carry on, but this is an extremely bad practice and absolutely not recommended.

Comment: I have tried the above method and the system can boot into login prompt. However, I don't know how to figure out the SELinux problem.

Comment: Hello mate, you can disable SELinux if you are just using this on a desktop - you can use getenforce and sestatus to see the current status of SELinux - to disable it, set it into permissive mode by editing /etc/sysconfig/selinux (read the comments - they are helpful).  If this is however a server then please do not disable SELinux. Instead diagnose the issue - most likely a problem with your filesystem. SELinux runs a pseudo-filesystem on top of the normal filesystem. Have a look here http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-fsrelabel.html

Comment: I made a mistake in /etc/selinux/config, and got kernel panic after reboot. I fixed it as described!

Comment: @Alex When I try to edit the `config` file, it says comes back with an error of `bash: config: Read-only file system`. Any ideas on how to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

here is a related post about selinux and messages such as : "Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted "

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867591/how-to-solve-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-without-er